# Filtering a long list of links

Tags: jquery

I am breaking my head over this piece of code

```
$('a').filter(function() {
    // I want to eleminate www.goto.com, www.foto.com
    // and 10-15 additional links
    return this.href.match(??);
}).addClass('highlight');
```

On the page there are about 50 links and I want to filter 10-15 of them. I do not want to write multiple if's. Not when I am using jQuery. I also cannot add a class or id to the links as the markup is beyond my reach.

Mark up here - http://jsfiddle.net/wQYuz/

How do I go about it?

Comment: What is your criteria? How do you know which links to filter and which ones to keep?

Comment: I just have the list with me. It goes like www.goto.com, www.foto.com, and so on. About 10 of them.

Comment: You can use [`indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) method.

Comment: are you assuming the ones to eliminate are in a particular order? I wish, but they are not!

Comment: No I'm not, as @NathanKoop mentions, what is the criteria? Which elements should be selected?

Comment: Ok I will try again. There are about 50 links on the page. Out of the 50, barring 10 links (which are given to me in say an array), all the others must have the class 'highlight' applied to.

Comment: @undefined what did you have in mind when you mentioned indexOf(). Sorry I interrupted you!

Comment: hey @KayKay you should edit your question to include the information about the array

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var elm = ["http://www.goto.com", "http://www.foto.com"]; //list of unwanted sites
$("a").each(function () {
    var href = $(this).attr("href");
    if (elm.indexOf(href) >= 0) { //compare
        $(this).addClass("highlite");
    }
});
```

[Fiddle here.](http://jsfiddle.net/wQYuz/4/)

Comment: fyi: your fiddle has the remove function in it instead of the highlite.

Comment: This looks interesting. I will try it out

Answer (score 0):

You said you wanted to remove all links with given URL (i.e. goto foto) and then highlight the rest. So you could remove all the hrefs first, then highlight the rest

http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/WbYUe/

```
$('a').filter(function() {
// I want to eleminate www.goto.com, www.foto.com
// and 10 more links
  return this.href.match(/(goto|foto|anyotherstring)/g);
}).remove();

$('a').each(function(){
  $(this).addClass("highlite");
});
```

OR

You could do the following, which removes the given links and highlights the others all in one turn

http://jsfiddle.net/fenderistic/aCZfa/

```
$('a').each(function() {
  // I want to eleminate www.goto.com, www.foto.com
  // and 10 more links
  if(this.href.match(/(xyz|goto|foto|mymy|abc)/g)){
   this.remove();   
} else { $(this).addClass("highlite"); }
  //return this.href.match(/(goto|foto|anyotherstring)/g);
});
```

Comment: Any perf benefit doing so?

Comment: Well it avoids using many `if` statements and avoids using a `switch` statement

Answer (score -1):

This will do the job:

```
$('a').filter(function() {
   // I want to eleminate www.goto.com, www.foto.com
   // and 10 more links
    return this.href.match(/oto|xyz|loop/g);
}).addClass('highlite');
```

It is comparing the `oto` pattern against each link and the matching ones get `highlited`.

Here is the updated fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wQYuz/5/

Comment: Ha! Thanks but not all the sites have an oto soundex. There are sites like www.puff.com and www.like.com in the list too.

Comment: You can list the different kind of conditions in the match, I've just updated the fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/wQYuz/5/